# Seeking Name of Abstract, Card-Based RPG

Tags: indie-rpg, product-identification

I'm looking for the name of a small, indie RPG that I came across a while ago. The game used tarot-like cards instead of dice. When something in the game needed to be decided, then cards were drawn and the results interpreted. I remember the game dealing with a lot of abstract concepts and archtypes. Can anyone direct me to the name of this particular game?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like "Everway," which came out in the mid-1990s from Wizards of the Coast.

Comment: Everway it is. Check out this site for resources. http://www.everway.homecall.co.uk/Everway/Everway.htm

Comment: Also try http://netfiles.uiuc.edu/rwb/www/gaming/everweb/